# How do I skip some roles tasks when testing with Ansible Molecule?

Tags: ansible, molecule

What is the easiest way to skip some role tasks when I perform functional testing using Ansible Molecule?

Answer (score 12):

There are two tags you can use which are implicit when code is run by molecule [`notest` and `molecule-notest`](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html?highlight=notest#id17).

Example:

```
- name: my task
  tags: notest
  shell: sudo rm -rf /
```

Comment: And if you want to run the task only when testing with molecule and skip it otherwise you can have a conditional like this: `when: '"molecule-notest" in ansible_skip_tags'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the additional command line arguments to the ansible-playbook command to skip tags like this:

```
molecule converge -- --skip-tags="<your role>"
```

To use this option you have to tag your task first as https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216583/7066745 indicates

Source: https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html